# Discord bot dont return all members

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i making a discord bot, and wanna add `!server` command to view server info. i add members section, but it returns 1, but my server have 2 human member and 4 bots(all my) Why? This is code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def server(ctx):
    membersInServer = ctx.guild.members
    botsInServer = list(filter(filterOnlyBots, membersInServer))
    serv_emb = discord.Embed(title = f'Info about server {ctx.guild.name}')
    serv_emb.add_field(name = 'Members', value = f'All: {len(membersInServer)}\nBots: {len(botsInServer)}')
    await ctx.send(embed = serv_emb)
```

Comment: Either downgrade your dependency to `discord.py>=1.4,<1.5` or use the new gateway but enable intents, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#intents-primer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not relying on an older version of `discord.py`, as that will probably prevent you from accessing new features and bug fixes in the future.

First, enable the *Members* privileged intent on your Discord application by going to `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<app_id>/bot` and checking "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT".

Then, use the Members intents in the following way:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# The remainder of your code...
```

And you're ready to get going!

Comment: hey, why did i not marked it as answer two years ago? just found out i was asking this... tho i dont even use discord now